# How to add ads in react native, Expo PWA

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, admob, progressive-web-apps

I have an Expo, React native mobile app and I am using react-native-google-mobile-ads to show banners and interstitials. Now I am trying to make and PWA and the problem is that this library uses native modules and when I try to compile web it throws an error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5vhN.png). Is there any workaround to use native modules conditionally or any ads alternative?

I have tried to put conditionally blocks where native code is used, but the problem is that the error happens when I compile web.

[Conditionally blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUPKT.png)

Is this case the TestIds.ADAPTIVE_BANNER line throws error when I compile.

EDIT: I achieve to make different screens for web and native using .web.tsx and .tsx extensions, now the problem is that in web I don't have ads, is there a thing similar to banners and interstitials to use in web?